# Backup stored procedure for full, differential and log backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, backup, sql-server-2012

I wrote a simple stored procedure for backing up FULL, Differential and LOG backup. This is my stored procedure:

```
Alter PROCEDURE BackupDB
(   
    @BaseLocation   varchar(1024),
    @BackupType     varchar(32)

)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @DBName     varchar(255) = db_name()

    Declare @FileName   varchar(256)

    Declare @Date datetime = getdate()
    Set @BackupType = UPPER(@BackupType)

    Set @FileName = @DBName + '_'  + Cast(Year(@Date) as varchar(4)) + '_' + 
                    Right('00' + Cast(Month(@Date) as varchar(2)),2) + '_' +
                    Right('00' + Cast(Day(@Date) as varchar(2)),2) + '_' + 
                    Right('00' + Cast(DatePart(hh,@Date) as varchar(2)),2) + '_' + 
                    Right('00' + Cast(DatePart(mi,@Date) as varchar(2)),2) + '_' +
                    Right('00' + Cast(DatePart(ss,@Date) as varchar(2)),2) + '_' + 
                    Right('000' + Cast(DatePart(ms,@Date) as varchar(3)),3) + '_' + UPPER(@BackupType) +                    
                    (Case When @BackupType = 'FULL' Or @BackupType = 'DIFFERENTIAL' Then '.BAK' Else '.TRN' End)

    Declare @FullPath varchar(1280) = ''

    If Right(@BaseLocation,1) <> '\'
    Begin
        Set @BaseLocation = @BaseLocation + '\'
    End
    Set @FullPath = @BaseLocation + @FileName
    Print @FullPath


    If @BackupType = 'FULL'
    Begin
        Backup database @DBName To Disk = @FullPath
    End
    Else If @BackupType = 'DIFFERENTIAL'
    Begin
        Backup database @DBName To Disk = @FullPath WITH DIFFERENTIAL
    End
    Else If @BackupType = 'LOG'
    Begin
        BACKUP LOG @DBName
             TO Disk = @FullPath
    End

END
GO
```

I ran my stored procedure and it seems to work perfectly for parameters passed in. Now the next step is to create a SQL JOB for this. However before I do this, I want to know is this correct procedure? I've read many articles and they all seem to point out one line "Test backup strategy."

Now I would be creating a SQL JOB weekly, daily and every 5 minutes i.e Weekly full backups, Daily Differential and Log backups every 5 minutes.

Do you think this stored procedure is incorrectly written or do you think it should be all fine for my scenario?

Comment: Your store procedure loosk no problem. And you have tested it. But why don't you just use MaintenancePlan, you can create weekly full backup plan, daily differential backup plan, daily transactionlog backup plan. I think that is more stable than your store procedure + job. And you also need to add exception hanlding and error log, maintenance plan automatically maintain the history and log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks good to me, if this is a programming exercise, fine. (you need to include error trapping and reporting). However if your not using SQL express, then as pointed out above, a maintenance plan will do all this with error reporting. If you are using SQL Express, then for free SQLBackupAndFTP http://sqlbackupandftp.com/ is a fine program which I've used and recommended for years. It has excellent error reporting which I experienced recently, when msdb became corrupt. It will also backup to an Amazon S3 account (paid version but not much). Full story here: http://ava.co.uk/blog/2013/3/21/a-backup-problem-and-the-solution.aspx